# How to prove this process to be a martingale?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, conditional-expectation, martingales

Suppose we have $(X_n)$ a sequence of real positive random variables in $\mathcal L^2$ that is $\mathcal F_n$ mesurable

Let:

$S_n=X_1+\dots+X_n$ with $S_0=0$

$A_n=\sigma_1^2+\dots+\sigma_n^2$ with $A_0=0$

$V_n=S_n^2-A_n$

Given that $\mathbb E[X_n |\mathcal F_{n-1}]=0$ and $\mathbb E[X_n^2|F_{n-1}]=\sigma_n^2$

Show that $(S_n)$ and $(V_n)$ are martingales.

**My problem:**

I proved that $(S_n)$ is a martingale simply using the fact that $\mathbb E[X_n |\mathcal F_{n-1}]=0$ but I don't know how am I going to prove that $(V_n)$ is a martingale since the calculation gets complicated if I try to pull out the $X_n^2$ from $S_n^2$ to use the second property.

Comment: Hint. $\mathbf{E}^{\mathcal{F}_n}S_{n+1} = \mathbf{E}^{\mathcal{F}_n}(S_n+X_{n+1})^2 = S_n^2 + \sigma_{n+1}^2~$ (why?)

Comment: @charlus is it because $S_n$ is $\mathcal F_n$ mesurable so $E[S_nX_{n+1}|F_n]=S_nE[X_{n+1}|F_n]=0$?

Comment: Precisely! You should be able to complete the proof from here